# .NET Core DB seeding from a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to seed SQL database (localhost server) table named Contacts with about 200,000 contact records to test out my search efficiency in C#. I am using .NET Core 2.2 and seeding the database via code-first approach. In order to get 200,000 records, I have a text file with about 450 first names and another text file with another 450 last names. I am then looping through these two files using StreamReader (code below) to create contact objects

```
// Model
public class Contact
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder, int recordCounter)
{
    builder.ToTable("Contacts");
    builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    builder.Property(t => t.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired();
    builder.Property(t => t.FirstName).IsRequired();
    builder.Property(t => t.LastName).IsRequired();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@".\FirstName.txt")) 
    {
        string firstName;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
        // the file is reached.
        while ((firstName = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@".\LastName.txt")) 
            {
                string lastName;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((lastName = sr2.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    // negative value Id to avoid collision with non-seed data
                    builder.HasData(new Contact
                        {
                            Id = -(recordCounter),
                            FirstName = firstName,
                            LastName = lastName
                        }
                    );
                    recordCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

I am capturing the number of Contact records, and using that to iterate over another two files named StreetName.txt and CityState.txt to create a single address for each of the Contact records. The passed in Contact records count is incremented in the loop and assigned as a foreign key to the Addresses table.

I am similarly creating telephone numbers (using Random number generator) and email records for the Contacts and inserting them in Telephones and Emails tables where in the number of Contact records is incremented and passed in as foreign key.

The issue I am having is shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Other points that may be of interest:

> 1. I have my wireless network turned off so that Microsoft does not force any updates overnight while my VS 2017 was running.
> 2. The text files reside in the same folder as Startup.cs file
> 3. I am using .NET Core 2.2 and EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.6)
> 4. The VBCSCompiler memory usage shot as high as 8500 MB at various times.
> 5. The other entries that was shown as having high Power Usage in the Task Manager window were Visual Studio and System. Surprisingly, SQL
>      Server VSS Writer indicated in the screenshot had "very low" power
>      usage.
> 6. I am using VS 2017 Enterprise edition.
> 7. I could step through my code without any compilation errors before the migration was applied.
> 8. My machine is slow to respond, but has not crashed since starting the program (indicating that there are no infinite loops or memory leaks happening).

I am wondering if I should wait longer for the program to complete? Can someone explain what "phase" is Visual Studio currently in? Is it "stuck" at some line of code? I could successfully loop through the code before I applied the "seed-large-db" migration to seed my database. Applying "seed-large-db" migration seems to have successfully created the file (file size over 800 MB).

Please educate me on things that I may not know with code first migration, visual studio inner working, local instance of SQL server etc.

Comment: Your overall approach aside, you're opening and closing the last name file multiple times, requiring repeated  disk IO. At the very least, load the names once into a collection and then iterate over that. You could also possibly parallelize the processing.

Comment: I agree with pinky. Getting data from a hard drive is much much slower than directly from memory. Also once you generate all those names you could save those to a file and load them directly up from that file.

Comment: I don't know if I necessarily agree with the disk IO slowing the process down. I could step through the code very quickly (not with 18h). I was wondering if SQL writitng process is the issue as it is trying to ensure referential integrity of the data with the Contact FK in the address, email and telephone tables... Also, does anyone has any insight about why the code see to be stuck at the line "Build started: Project: Contact.API, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ----" in the VS2017 Output window in the screenshot?

Comment: Even if you don't agree, I think it's worth trying it out. Also, EF migrations may not be the best way to seed so many records. My guess is that it's making a db call per record, plus tracking the entities and a bunch of other housekeeping. It might work fine for a small set of data, but 200k records (plus all the address/phone ones) is a lot. Try instead to use something like SqlBulkCopy if you need to generate this amount of data.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you for providing alternative to my approach (SqlBulkCopy). I will continue my investigation with the original question  for the long term, and look at your suggestion for making progress in the short term so that I can check the efficiency of my "Search" function (which started this whole exercise).